# Angular ng-repeat complex table (array of arrays)

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm new Angular developer who needs help with ng-repeat. I have some complex json which i want to print in a table(`<table>`) or in orderd list (`<ol>`).

JSON

```
{
    "arrays": [
        [
            [1,2,3,4],
            [2,3,4,5],
            [3,4,5,6]
        ],
        [
            [1,2],
            [2,3],
            [4,5] 
        ] 
    ]
}
```

so, i have one array which contains n-arrays(2 in this example) and each of n-arrays contains the same number(3 in this example) of number-arrays. Each number-array of n-array part contains also the same number(first part of number-arrays has size 4 and the second part number-arrays has size 2)

And now i need something like that

```
#  |   Numbers
---------------------------------------
1  |   1     2    3    4    :    1    2
2  |   2     3    4    5    :    2    3
3  |   3     4    5    6    :    3    4
```

OR

```
1.    1    2    3    4    :    1    2
2.    2    3    4    5    :    2    3
3.    3    4    5    6    :    3    4
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a method to the controller to do the work for you.

#### controller

```
$scope.arrays = [
    [
        [1,2,3,4],
        [2,3,4,5],
        [3,4,5,6]
    ],
    [
        [1,2],
        [2,3],
        [4,5] 
    ] 
];

$scope.getRows = function () {
  var rows = [], i = 0;

  for (; i < $scope.arrays[0].length; i++) {
    rows.push($scope.arrays[0][i].concat(':', $scope.arrays[1][i]));
  } 

  return rows;
};
```

#### view

```
{{ getRows() | json }}
```

Comment: even if i retrun arrays from getRows function and print with {{getRows()}} nothing happend ..any solutions

Comment: No, but i have already figure it out. I had json in my variable so i had to access to array like this $scope.arrays.arrays[0].

It has also get printed in table, but besides that i'm getting error Error: [$rootScope:infdig] ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369406/ng-bind-html-gives-an-infinite-digest-error-rootscope-infdig ...do you now how to avoid that scope function ?