# Angular Bootstrap Tooltip Dynamic Content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am making a cart application in Angular using [Angular Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

When hovering over the cart icon a tooltip should appear. The tooltip's content should change based on if the item is already in the cart or not.

So, here is the html:

`<h3><i class="fa fa-shopping-basket" ng-click="add2Cart(item.Name)" tooltip-placement="right" uib-tooltip-html="itemtooltiptext(item.Name)" aria-hidden="true"></i></h3>`

Basically, in order to check if the item is already in the cart, I want the tooltip text to resolve from a function. My understanding from the documentation is this is supported as long as the HTML is trusted.

It says,

> `uib-tooltip-html` $ - Takes an expression that evaluates to an HTML string. Note that this HTML is not compiled. If compilation is required, please use the uib-tooltip-template attribute option instead. The user is responsible for ensuring the content is safe to put into the DOM!

So my `itemtooltiptext()` function is...

```
  $scope.itemtooltiptext = function(name) {
  if (localStorage.getItem("cart") === null) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml("Add " + name + " to Cart!");
  } else {
    var cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
    for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
      if (cart[i] == name) {
        console.log("already in cart");
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(name + "already in Cart!");
      }
    }
    return $sce.trustAsHtml("Add " + name + " to Cart!");
  }
}
```

This results in an

> Infinite $digest Loop Error

As detailed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19370032

But the problem is I need it to come from a function with the various conditions? So should I be using a template? I don't understand how that would work any better because I still need dynamic text served from the template... so what is the solution?

Thank you.

Comment: can you make up a [plunk](https://plnkr.co/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not how you use `uib-tooltip-html`, apparently it causes an infinite digest loop, fortunately [the demo plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/qPJt2g86QzN3RqW1ta0C?p=preview) shows you how to do it.

You need to get/calculate your html, bind to some scope variable and bind it into `uib-tooltip-html`

js

```
$scope.itemtooltiptext = function() {
    $scope.htmlTooltip = $sce.trustAsHtml('I\'ve been made <b>bold</b>!');
};
$scope.itemtooltiptext();
```

html

```
<button uib-tooltip-html="htmlTooltip" class="btn btn-default">Tooltip</button>
```

If you still want to bind a function to your tooltip, you can do like so

```
<button uib-tooltip="{{itemtooltiptext()}}" class="btn btn-default">Tooltip</button>
```

Note that this approache will have the function invoked every digest cycle.

Comment: FYI your plunk is blank!

Comment: fixed it, it's basically the unaltered ui-bootstrap demo plunk for the tooltip

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this infinite digest cycle issue where I needed a dynamic tooltip... it caused angular to recalculate it every time as a new value (even though it was the same).  I created a function to cache the computed value like so:

```
$ctrl.myObj = {
    Title: 'my title',
    A: 'first part of dynamic toolip',
    B: 'second part of dynamic tooltip',
    C: 'some other value',
    getTooltip: function () {
        // cache the tooltip
        var obj = this;
        var tooltip = '<strong>A: </strong>' + obj.A + '<br><strong>B: </strong>' + obj.B;
        var $tooltip = {
            raw: tooltip,
            trusted: $sce.trustAsHtml(tooltip)
        };
        if (!obj.$tooltip) obj.$tooltip = $tooltip;
        else if (obj.$tooltip.raw !== tooltip) obj.$tooltip = $tooltip;
        return obj.$tooltip;
    }
};
```

Then in the html, I accessed it like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.myObj.C"
    uib-tooltip-html="$ctrl.myObj.getTooltip().trusted">
```